# How to find lagged cross correlation between time series?

Tags: time-series, linear-regression, correlation

I have 2 time series, $X$ and $Y$, and I'm trying to find the best lag range that correlates $X$ to $Y$ (find the amount(s) of lag of $X$ that best correlate to the target variable $Y$).

For instance, if the best lag range is between $t = 8$ and $t = 10$, then the final equation would be $Y_t = \alpha_1 X_{t-8} + \alpha_2 X_{t-9} + \alpha_3 X_{t-10} + \alpha_4$.

Since the value of $Y$ could depend not only on some specific lag of $X$, but rather on a **range** of lags, I can't just find the correlation coefficient between $Y$ and different time lags of $X$ individually, and can't just run a regression model for several lags of $X$ as independent variables, since there are huge colinearities between those lags (series $X$ is a slow-changing time series).

Is there a way to find what are the best lags of $X$ to be used to predict my variable $Y$?

Comment: Cross-correlograms

Comment: " the correlation coefficient between Y and different time lags of X  individually" Would you elaborate? Since the X and Y is function of t, shouldn't one delay to entire Y signal applied to each point at each t?

Answer (score 2):

This is commonly called cross-correlation, lagged regression, or [distributed lag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lag).

One commonly applied algorithm is [ARMAX model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model#ARMAX).